# Combining numeric values that have been converted from text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I built a survey tool that our customer service agents use to track survey results. For ease, the agent simply chooses a survey value (text) from a drop down menu. There is data being collected from 5 columns. The formula seems to work best to convert the text response to a numeric value is -

`=IF(C2="VH",5,IF(C2="SH",4,IF(C2="N",3,IF(C2="SU",2,""))))`  where VH is the survey response, and 5 is the numeric value I want associated with it.

My question is pretty simple -- how can I take this the next step and calculate averages (IN a single cell) based on the numeric responses from all 5 columns?

Comment: If you're doing your translation into cells `H2:L2`, then `=AVERAGE(H2:L2)` does it. But I'm thinking that you're trying to do something more difficult, right?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is not clear what you asking based on what information you have given. What columns are you averaging? The only column you gave in your example is `C`.

Comment: Hey Charlie! Yeah, it's a little more complicated. I just gave the formula I'm using for text to number conversion based on a single cell. The survey includes data from 5 columns of each row. Each cell in the row needs to be combined with the others and averaged to provide a numerical value to be later used for metrics. Not sure why I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to choose a column based on your formula, you could use
    =AVERAGE(INDEX(A1:E100;0;5))
where A1:E100 is the range of all your columns and 5 is the result of your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 5 columns are from C to G, and you want to calculate that average using your formula to convert text to number you need the following:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(C4:G4="VH",5,IF(C4:G4="SH",4,IF(C4:G4="N",3,IF(C4:G4="SU",2,"")))))
```

Enter with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>